# Google script works only for data manually entered and not for data brought in through importrange in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script to hide those rows which contains the word - 'Matured' (in column F)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if (sheet.getName() == "Follow-ups LAPL" && r.getColumnIndex() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Matured")
  sheet.hideRows(r.getRowIndex(),1);
```

The problem is - the script does the job of hiding the row only when the 'Matured' is entered MANUALLY (in column F), **but it does not work if the same is brought in through importrange (in same column F).**

Is it by design, or is there any workaround?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes. That's by design. It only responds to user actions.

Answer (score 0):

It is by design. You may trigger the `onchange` event rather than the `onEdit` event for your use case or you may trigger both. See if `onChange` works in both cases, if so you may trigger only that. If it doesn't then you may trigger both events at the same time.
You may trigger multiple events on the same function by going to the Current Project's trigger as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Hi Riyafa! Thanx for your response. I tried both ways but unfortunately its not working (working only for new entries but not for data brought forward through importrange).  I prepared a spreadsheet if you care to see. The project name for the script is AutoHide. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XdcKbxKvIOSFK37zwULZns6giE9ounHPS5iHrRFkvIk/edit#gid=946095724

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function and trigger every minute. But make sure in master spreadsheet (*Spreadsheet id which you included in importrange*) you delete empty cells or else in below loop **sheet.getLastRow()** will count empty cells too which will result in unnecessary iteration.

```
function onModified() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET ID');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Follow-ups LAPL");
    var getData = sheet.getRange(1, 6, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    Logger.log(getData.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
        if (getData[i][0] == "Matured") {
            sheet.hideRows(i+1,1);
        } else {
            sheet.showRows(i+1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ritz! Thanx for your response. I tried your script unfortunately its not working (working only for new entries but not for data brought forward through importrange). I prepared a spreadsheet if you care to see. The project name for the script is AutoHide. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XdcKbxKvIOSFK37zwULZns6giE9ounHPS5iHrRFkvIk/edit#gid=946095724

Comment: If i will delete empty cells in master spreadsheet how will people enter data?

Comment: did you set trigger for the function `onModified()?` I am not saying to delete all the entire blank cells....you can leave up-to 100 blank cells...but best option is not to use `importrange` instead fetch the range from script.